# Fill objects fields from Stream<Integer>

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I have class

```
@Data
Test{
  private int[] a;
  private int[] b;
}
```

And I have private `Stream<Integer> stream` with 1 000 000 integers.

How can I make the following:

1. iterate over all integers in stream
2. create new Test
3. if `i!=0` add `i` to `test.a` else add `i` to `test.b`

At last I need a Test object with 2 arrays where a contains all non-zero elements and b contains all zeroes.

I need 1 Test object.

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: You should be using an IntStream, not a Stream<Integer>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use 2 stream operations and on 1 instance of the test use setters for a and b.

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>();
        myList.add(1);
        myList.add(0);
        myList.add(1);
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setA(myList.stream().filter(x -> x != 0).mapToInt(x -> x).toArray());
        t.setB(myList.stream().filter(x -> x == 0).mapToInt(x -> x).toArray());
        System.out.println("t: " + t);

    }

}

class Test {
    private int[] a;
    private int[] b;

    public void setA(int[] array) {
        a = array;
    }

    public void setB(int[] array) {
        b = array;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Test {a=" + Arrays.toString(a) + ", b=" + Arrays.toString(b) + "}";
    }

}
```

Comment: But I have 1000 000 integers. If I create 2 streams I need make 2 000 000 iterations

Answer (score 1):

If you know beforehand that you have 1,000,000 integers, there is no need to collect zeros at all:

```
int[] a = stream.mapToInt(Integer::intValue).filter(i -> i!=0).toArray();
int[] b = new int[1_000_000 - a.length];
Test test = new Test(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample implementation that splits the Stream into two Streams

```
public class Main {

static class Test {
    private int[] a;
    private int[] b;

    Test(int[] a, int[] b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntStream.Builder zeroStreamBuilder = IntStream.builder();
    IntStream.Builder nonZeroStreamBuilder = IntStream.builder();

    IntStream intStream = IntStream.of(0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
    intStream.forEach(value -> {
        if (value == 0)
            zeroStreamBuilder.add(value);
        else
            nonZeroStreamBuilder.add(value);
        }
    );

    int[] a = zeroStreamBuilder.build().toArray();
    int[] b = nonZeroStreamBuilder.build().toArray();
    Test result = new Test(a, b);
}
}
```

If you are willing to use a List, then it will be possible skip building arrays from streams `.build().toArray()` as you can directly add the values to the resulting lists.